# SQL subquery to determine whether or not a particular row is the first item that matches the subquery

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, asp.net, vb.net

Here is my VB.NET and SQL query (which is one of the things I'm particularly interested in having critiqued):

```
Private Sub BindHistory()

    Dim list = New List(Of CSRate)

    ' I hate the "case when" and subquery here - it seems like there should
    ' be a better way to do this
    Const Query As String =
        "select n.PayRate,
                n.CreatedOn,
                n.CreatedByUserName,
                (case when exists(select top 1 m.BusinessUnitID
                                  from TrackRates m
                                  where m.RateID = n.RateID AND
                                        m.TrackRateID < n.TrackRateID)
                 then 'entered rate of' else 'edited rate to' end) as Verb
        from    Rates, TrackRates n
        where   Rates.RateID = n.RateID AND
                Rates.ClientID = @id"
    Using reader = DBAccess.ExecuteReader(User.ActiveBusinessUnitID, CommandType.Text, Query, New SqlParameter("@id", SessionState.Client.ID))
        If reader.HasRows Then
            While reader.Read()
                Dim rate = New CSRate()
                rate.ActionDate = reader.Item("PayRate")
                rate.Action = $"User {reader.Item("Verb")} {reader.Item("PayRate")}"
                rate.UserID = reader.Item("CreatedByUserName")

                list.Add(rate)
            End While
        End If
    End Using

    CSHistory.DataSource = list
    CSHistory.DataBind()
End Sub
```

For the record, yes, I do realize that I should probably move the query to a stored procedure rather than having it "directly" in code-behind like this. Also, `n` and `m` are probably terrible names that I should refactor.

What I'm trying to accomplish with this SQL query is to determine whether a particular item is the first row that matches the criteria in the `where` clause (the text I have to display on the front end will differ). For example:

```
| TrackRateID | Other columns |
| 1           | ...           |
| 2           | ...           |
| 3           | ...           |
```

In this case, `2` and `3` should have the verb `edited rate to` (because there's a `TrackRateID` that's less than their `TrackRateID`) and `1` should have the verb `entered rate of`. (There is, of course, no guarantee that the "first" row will actually have an ID of `1`).

Here's my ASP.NET front-end code:

```
<div id="clientHistoryPopup" style="display:none">
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="CSHistory" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="User ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ActionDate" HeaderText="Date" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Action" HeaderText="Pay Rate History" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

The `case when` and subquery particularly irk me. If I'm reading this properly (and please correct me if I'm wrong because I'm not too confident about this point), this would make the whole thing `O(n log n)`.

Also, it seems like that makes the database logic too tightly "coupled" to my front-end logic, which strikes me as architecturally inappropriate.

Am I correct about the computational complexity? Is there a better way to do this that has a lower computational complexity and is less "coupled" to the front end?

Comment: If you had to avoid jargon like "subquery" and "case", could you describe what this query does, in words that an ordinary person would understand?

Comment: The two `Verb` cases seem backwards to me. Are you sure they shouldn't be swapped?

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean the first row? You don't have an order by in the subquery

Comment: @scsimon I edited

Comment: @200_success I edited

Comment: I *think* you could remove the sub query and use and over function (depending on your version of sql server). See if this gives you the expected result. `case when TrackRateID = Min(TrackRateID) over (partition by RateID order by TrackRateID) then 'entered rate of' else 'edited rate to' end`. But for your current sub query, you need an order by for top 1 to be deterministic. Without an order by top n doesn't guarantee the same results each time.

Comment: @200_success I think you're correct about them being backwards, actually.

Comment: @EJoshuaS did the window function work as expected?

Comment: @scsimon For some reason it was listing both as `entered rate of`

Comment: I think it would have been better to start with just the query on dba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no natural order.  With no order by the order of the rows is not guaranteed.

What you are looking for is not totally clear to me.  But I think this is what you are looking for.  Pretty sure [window function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) is what you are looking and it is efficient.

```
  select tt.AuctionID, tt.StartingPrice
       , tt.rn 
       , case when rn = 1 then 'first' else 'not first' end as [verb]
  from ( SELECT [AuctionID]
              , [Price]
              , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition [AuctionID] by order by [Price]) as rn
         FROM [Test].[dbo].[Auction]
       ) tt

select *
     , case when rn = 1 then 'entered rate of' else 'edited rate to' end as [verb]
from  ( select n.PayRate, n.CreatedOn, n.CreatedByUserName
            ,  row_number() over (partiton by RateID order by TrackRateID) as rn
          from Rates, TrackRates n
         where ClientID = @id 
      ) tt
 order by RateID, TrackRateID
```